# set table td width overflow text wrap

Tags: css

I have a table

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>dfa sdfs fsafsdfasdfs dfsdf dsf</td><td>sdfds fdasfsffsdfsdfsdffsfd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dfas dfs</td><td>sdfdsf dasfs ffsd fsdfsdfsfd</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>dfasdfsdffsdfdfasdfsd fsdf dsf</td><td>ssdffsfd</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and I need the long columns to not stretch out the table but to word wrap.
how can i do this

I ultimately need each column to have a width of 50px.

Answer (score 2):

You want to do this in CSS, so like this.

```
table td{
  width:50px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
td{
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

this should work for you

Comment: also add `width: 50px` to the CSS property